# Learning mathematica, ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, dynamic

I am trying to teach my self Mathematica. I am working with the following example:

```
V= Range[370000, 770000, 20000]
x = 7;
y = 6;
\[Alpha] = 2;
L == CubeRoot[(V x^2)/(\[Alpha] y)];
B == CubeRoot[(V y^2)/(\[Alpha] x)];
d == CubeRoot[(\[Alpha]^2 V)/(x y)];
ListPlot[{L, B, d}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[m^3], HoldForm[m]}]
```

When I plot the results on the y-axis I get 1, 2, ,3...21, which corresponds to the number of variables generated by `Range` and not the actual variable i.e. 370 000, 390 000,....,770 000.

However, I would like on the y-axis to have the actual variable. I hope I am clear enough. If you try to run the code you will see what I mean.

Thank you in advance for your help .

Comment: You should avoid starting your variables or functions with uppercase letters, you may clash with built-ins. (`N` for instance.) Also, `==` is a test for equality, so `L,B,d` are probably not what you think. By y axis do you mean x axis? You can add the option `DataRange->V[[{1,-1}]]` to `ListPlot` or you can make each list, `L,B,d` a list of pairs. e.g. `L=Transpose@{V,CubeRoot[(V x^2)/(\[Alpha] y)]}`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the helpful comments :) yes I mean x-axis.... sorry for the slopiness.

Comment: N.J. Evans the Transpose did the trick! thank you very much for the usefull comment!